# all IPs of an instance group

Tags: google-cloud-platform

How can I get a list into some sort of text file of all of the external IPs associated with my instance group.  I can have hundreds of machines in my instance group and the vm list just isn't practical.

Answer (score 3):

The external IP of a GCE instance can not be retrieved directly from an instance group, it is attached to an instance, which means you have to pull it from the instance details.I can think of two ways in achieving this -

1. (Slower) - Get the list of instances in the instance group, and loop through each instance to get its external IP. The `gcloud` cli tool can help with this, use the `--format` and `--filter` options to get specific fields and filter specific instances -
   `gcloud compute instance-groups managed list-instances --help`
2. (Faster) -  For managed instance groups(MIGs), there is a `baseInstanceName` attribute used to name instances under the MIG i.e. every instance under the MIG will have that prefix as it's name. Assuming those instances with that prefix belong to the instance group, you can use below command to pull external IPs

Say your instance group's name is "testig", get the `baseInstanceName` first -

`prefix=$(gcloud compute instance-groups managed list --format='value(baseInstanceName)' --filter='name~^testig')`

Then get instance name and external IP of instances -

`gcloud compute instances list --filter="name~^${prefix}" --format='value(name,networkInterfaces[0].accessConfigs[0].natIP)'`